# I have the information, how do I get it into my db?

Tags: php, mysqli

I figured out how to run Arp-scan and show the results on the page.  Now I need to insert the information into a Mysql DB.  I know how to insert a single record, but I struggle with how to get many records into the db.  Can't seem to wrap my head around it.  Here's my code

```
    <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "mydb");
    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $output = shell_exec("sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet --numeric --          quiet| grep -e 80:82:87");
foreach (explode("\n", $output) as $host)
{
    list($ip, $mac) = array_pad(explode("\t", $host),2,null);

    echo "$ip  $mac<br>";
}
// attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO phones (ipadd, mac) VALUES ('$ip', '$mac')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Put your sql query inside of your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$values = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $output) as $host)
{
    list($ip, $mac) = array_pad(explode("\t", $host),2,null);
    $values[] = '("'.$ip.'", "'.$mac.'")';
}
// attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO phones (ipadd, mac) VALUES ".implode(',', $values);
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

It will create an array of strings in following format:

```
("IP", "MAC")
```

and connect them later using a comma

```
("IP", "MAC"),("IP2", "MAC2")
```

and add into the query

Comment: That works just fine, for one small thing.  It enters a blank row into the table.  Otherwiae that is exactly what I am needing!

Comment: There might be a problem with your code that extracts ip and mac from the output. I didn't tested it with arp-scan output to be honest.